# bourne shell lower case

Tags: sh

Is there a way to make bourne shell not care about case on string comparisons? alternatively, can I convert a variable to all lowercase?

I was trying to use tr with echo, but never could get it to overwrite my variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just tried

```
MYVAR="This is a Test."
MYVAR=$(echo $MYVAR | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
echo $MYVAR
```

and the result was

```
this is a test.
```

Comment: apparently i was missing the parens around echo. Fml.

Comment: an even simpler method would be `$(echo ${MYVAR,,})` for lowercase and `$(echo ${MYVAR^^}` for uppercase

Comment: @Dehalion ${FOO,,} is a new substitution provided by Bash 4, it's not available for the POSIX standard bourne shells.

Comment: Please note that `tr` does not always work correctly with accent characters and umlauts. @Andreas solution definitely won't work with them. For a more reliable solution you have to resort to `gawk` (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/319666/39087)

Answer (score 3):

Please note that the given answer is for **bash**, not for Bourne shell which doesn't know 
**$(...)** constructs.
Also the **tr** classes **upper**, **lower** etc. do not exist in all tr implementations, it depends on which platform you are on (on Solaris you would use /usr/xpg4/bin/tr instead of /usr/bin/tr).
A proper **Bourne shell with classic tr** answer is:

```
MYVAR=`echo "$MYVAR" | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
```

Since you are happy with the given answer: fine, and that is probably ok for most readers given the ubiquity of bash.

You should have tagged the question correctly though: bourne-shell is misleading.

Comment: The bourrne shell *knows* the $(...) constructs, `` is deprecated in POSIX standard. See https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2006.